# Auth::user & sessions with Socialite

Tags: php, laravel

**FIXED THE ISSUE**

I had `<a href='{{ Auth::logout }}'>Logout</a>` which caused every page to log the user out.

---

**app/Http/Controllers/SocialAuthFacebookController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;
use App\Services\SocialFacebookAccountService;
use Auth;

class SocialAuthFacebookController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * Create a redirect method to facebook api.
   *
   * @return void
   */
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Return a callback method from facebook api.
     *
     * @return callback URL from facebook
     */
    public function callback(SocialFacebookAccountService $service)
    {
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser( Socialite::driver('facebook')->user() );
        Auth::login($user,true);
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

**app/SocialFacebookAccount.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SocialFacebookAccount extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'provider_user_id', 'provider'];

  public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

**app/Services/SocialFacebookAccountService.php**

```
namespace App\Services;
use App\SocialFacebookAccount;
use App\User;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User as ProviderUser;

class SocialFacebookAccountService
{
    public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
    {
        $account = SocialFacebookAccount::whereProvider('facebook')
            ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {

            $account = new SocialFacebookAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'facebook'
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

            if (!$user) {
                $user = User::create([
                    'email'    => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                    'name'     => $providerUser->getName(),
                    'password' => md5(rand(1,10000)),
                    'image'    => $providerUser->getAvatar(),
                ]);
            }

            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();

            return $user;
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently using Facebook and that works out so this is **not** what I'm asking.

I have this snippet on my master.blade.php and it works when I first sign into Facebook however when I go onto another page, such as `/about` it logs me out. I've tried `Auth::viaRemember` but this does nothing.

How do I store the user's credential in a session so that users won't get logged out just for moving to another page?!

Comment: Check [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-social-authentication-with-socialite) to see if you are missing something. ?

Comment: @Mihir Bhende I did follow that but no success :(

Comment: Is  your session driver working normally without socialite?

Comment: @MihirBhende Done a few tests and it doesn't seem like it is! How to fix it?

Comment: What driver yo are using? Can you show your session configurations please?

Comment: I'm using the default for 5.7, I haven't touched anything with sessions

Comment: If you use laravel's default login/register without socialite, is it maintaining session when you move between pages?

Comment: @MihirBhende Just added my code

Answer (score 0):

The facebook api will valid your request and give some basic user details only..you have to store the user details in your db first(after fb api request successfull) and then you have to start session with saved user id (Using AuthLoginUsingID function).

Comment: show me your for user store codes after facebook login successfull and creating session

Comment: public function callback(SocialFacebookAccountService $service)
    {
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser( Socialite::driver('facebook')->user() );
        Auth::login($user,true);
        return redirect()->to('/');
    } in tis code you are not saving the user details in User Model..save the user details which is come from facebook and save it in your user model then only you can make the user as logged in

Comment: isn't that Auth::login() job?

Comment: If you need to log an existing user instance into your application, you may call the login method with the user instance. The given object must be an implementation of the  Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract. The App\User model included with Laravel already implements this interface.It will validate user from App\User model only. so the user data must be stored in your app users table